# I want to develop an iPhone app using AIR and ActionScript 3 and I need the app to receive MIDI. How?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, coremidi

I am not entirely sure of how these associations work. iOS implements CoreMIDI. Ok. It's possible to build an app with CoreMIDI support with XCode and objective C. I don't own a Mac and I am absolutely appalled at the look of Objective C. I don't know if I want to learn that. I just stumbled upon the possibility of coding an app with Flash CS5 using actionscript 3.0.

My understanding is that I code my source in AS3 and during compilation it is ported into a native iOS app. Is that correct?

I want to develop an app that plays backing tracks during a live performance with the ability to loop regions of the currently playing track and the ability to control it with MIDI, more specifically a foot pedal / MIDI keyboard, etc...

Can I do that with AS3 & AIR? Or do I have to bow down to the fact that in order to make MIDI work I need to learn Objective C and do the thing with XCode?

Comment: maybe this could help: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications writing on as3 for iOS running in AVM. They are not compiled in native iOS code.

If you want to use CoreMIDI, you can write [NativeExtension](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html), that allow call native code wrapped with an ActionScript.

Or you can try use some of ActionScript MIDI libraries. For exapmle [MidAs3](http://code.google.com/p/midas3/wiki/MidAs3)

Comment: It does not necessarily need to be CoreMIDI, it can be any MIDI as far as I am concerned. If I use MidAs3, will the final app work in iOS?